# Wordpress delete cache postmeta

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using [Profi Search form](http://profisearchform.com/) and [Advanced Custom field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). 
Profi Search Form allows me to filter my posts through my custom fields.

The problem is that it's allows me to me to filter with fields I deleted through the interface ACF dashboard.

How can I permanently delete these custom fields ?

Comment: try ctrl +f5 to refresh the screen for the easiest answer its more than likely just browser cached.

Comment: Since Profi search is a paid plugin, I would check with them for support.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.
I contacted the author and I'm wainting for his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the two solutions I've found :

- Delete these posts meta in the database, with MySQL.
- Use a plugin like "[WP-Cleanup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clean-up/)" and delete revisions